# Springboard Quit Unexpectedly for Empty Swift Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, springboard

I created a new swift project, and changed nothing to the project. It is just an empty swift project. If I choose to run on iPhone 6, the springboard will crash. But if I choose others (like iPhone 5s or resizeable iPhone, even iPhone 6 Plus), the empty project works fine.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my xcode? And how should I deal with this problem?

The error message was so long that I cannot attach the whole message here. I'll choose some part that seems important to me.

```
Process:               SpringBoard [1047]

Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:            SpringBoard
Version:               1.0 (50)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [1035]
Responsible:           launchd_sim [1035]
User ID:               501
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)
Report Version:        11
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 110.4 - Device: iPhone 6 - Runtime: iOS 8.1 (12B411) - DeviceType: iPhone 6

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 714
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 160

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=283.3M resident=110.5M(39%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=172.8M(61%)
Writable regions: Total=176.0M written=49.6M(28%) resident=67.4M(38%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=108.6M(62%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG raster data                     2252K
CoreAnimation                       324K
CoreData Object IDs                4100K
CoreServices                        524K
CoreUI image data                   240K
Dispatch continuations             8192K
Foundation                            4K
Image IO                             12K
Kernel Alloc Once                     8K
MALLOC                            105.3M
MALLOC (admin)                       32K
OpenGL GLSL                         128K
SQLite page cache                   128K
STACK GUARD                        56.1M
Stack                              21.8M
VM_ALLOCATE                        16.7M
__DATA                             35.2M
__GLSLBUILTINS                      952K
__LINKEDIT                         70.9M
__TEXT                            212.5M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        89.9M
shared memory                        68K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             625.5M

Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B18, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.159.13.12)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Network Service: Thunderbolt Bridge, Ethernet, bridge0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

Comment: In your project, search setObjectForKey, or search the code that create dictionaries with keys and objects, log the keys.

Comment: Hi, I had searched the whole project and didn't find it. :(   Xcode lead me to the file called AppDelegate.swift, and showed "Thread 1: signal SIGTERM". The AppDelegate.swift file is generated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved automatically after I update my Xcode into the latest version.

If you have a possible answer for the question, you are still welcomed to answer the question.